# a page of my site not indexing by search console

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, google-search, search-engines, google-xml-sitemaps

i have a top rank product that from today i noticed that the page is missing from google search result . then i have tried to request manually index the page. after some days there is no chance.
i have added some sentences to product page and some edit and then i have changed the url and redirected to specified page. until today google not crawling the page again.
page url: [https://gymarket.ir/product/mpc-پودر-پروتئین-شیر-پگاه-70درصد-5کیلو/](https://gymarket.ir/product/mpc-%D9%BE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%A6%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D9%BE%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-70%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B5%D8%AF-5%DA%A9%DB%8C%D9%84%D9%88/)

Comment: You might have to ask Google about this. I'd check:1) that it's not excluded by your robots.txt; 2) that there are no meta properties on the page that look like 'noindex'; 3) that the page is in your XML sitemap; 4) any errors in your server logs for that page, or in the search console.

Comment: I've tried curl on that URL and I've had four redirects so far. Why so many? Maybe Google gives up if you make too many redirects. They all say "x-redirect-by: Yoast SEO Premium" so maybe you've set up Yoast wrong? I'd ask them for help since you're a premium customer.

Comment: @Rup hi, how you checked external redirects?

Comment: Oh possibly that was me getting it wrong. I'd have tried to run a `curl ---head` on that URL from a command prompt, and it's possible the character set got messed up pasting it into the command prompt, hence the redirects. So I could well have been mistaken.